# Can someone explain the formula + parameters needed to set a view relative to the mouse in a JScrollPane after zooming?

Tags: java, swing, awt, zooming

Below is a minimal reproducible code example. My code has no problems zooming in and out, but it seems that the offset calculations that I have done in the "setZoomFactor" method of the Drawing class, so that I can set the view to be relative to the mouse, are wrong. When you run the program, you have a word "Example" drawn with the drawString method. I am using it to test if my view is correct or not, as I do my zooming in while the mouse is placed over the "Example" written on the JScrollPane.

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestPane 
{
    public static Drawing d;
    public static double zoomFactor = 1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Tree Diagram");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new TestPane().makeDiagram());
        f.setSize(1600, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public JComponent makeDiagram()
    {
        d = new Drawing();

        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new TestPaneMouseListener();
        d.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        d.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        d.addMouseWheelListener(mouseAdapter);

        return new JScrollPane(d);
    }
}
```

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Drawing extends JPanel
{
    private final AffineTransform zoomTransform = new AffineTransform();
    private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1600, 800);
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
    
    public Drawing()
    {
        Font currentFont = getFont();
        Font newFont = currentFont.deriveFont(currentFont.getSize() * 5F);
        setFont(newFont);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    
    public void setZoomFactor(double zoomFactor) 
    {
        zoomTransform.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        Container container = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(this);
        
        double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
        
        double zoomDiv = TestPane.zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;

        xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
        yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;
        
        prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        
        ((JViewport) container).setViewPosition(new Point(-(int)xOffset, -(int)yOffset));
        
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        AffineTransform scrollTransform = g2d.getTransform();
        scrollTransform.concatenate(zoomTransform);
        g2d.setTransform(scrollTransform);

        g2d.drawString("Example", 300, 400);
            
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
    {
        Rectangle r = zoomTransform.createTransformedShape(rect).getBounds();
        return new Dimension(r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static testpane.TestPane.d;
import static testpane.TestPane.zoomFactor;

public class TestPaneMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
{ 
    private final Point origin = new Point();

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        Component c = e.getComponent();
        Container p = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(c);
        if (p instanceof JViewport) 
        {
            JViewport viewport = (JViewport) p;
            Point cp = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c, e.getPoint(), viewport);
            Point vp = viewport.getViewPosition();
            vp.translate(origin.x - cp.x, origin.y - cp.y);
            ((JComponent) c).scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vp, viewport.getSize()));
            origin.setLocation(cp);
        }
    }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
   {
       Component c = e.getComponent();
       Container p = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(c);
       if(p instanceof JViewport) 
       {
           JViewport viewport = (JViewport) p;
           Point cp = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c, e.getPoint(), viewport);
           origin.setLocation(cp);
       }
   }
   
   @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getWheelRotation()<0)
        {
            d.setZoomFactor(1.05);
            zoomFactor*=1.05;
        }
        
        if(e.getWheelRotation()>0)
        {
            d.setZoomFactor(1/1.05);
            zoomFactor/=1.05;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why my calculations for the view are wrong and how I can fix them?

Comment: Consider improving the focus of this question, telling what you've found, what you've tried and what *specifically* is confusing you. This can help reduce the chances of a question's being closed, can improve its odds of being re-opened if closed and can help get answers quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the viewport is 600 x 400 pixels.  The center point of the viewport is 300 x 200.

```
center x = x / 2
center y = y / 2
```

Let's also assume you have three images

1. 1600 x 1600 maximum zoom in
2. 1200 x 1200
3. 800 x 800 maximum zoom out.

You do all your graphics on the largest image and reduce the size of the image for the other two zoom levels.

To answer your question, let's further assume that the user is looking at the first image and clicks on the 400, 500 point to center the image.

To calculate the point that corresponds to viewport 0, 0 (center the image):

```
x = 400 - center x = 100
y = 500 - center y = 200
```

You place the origin of the viewpoint at image point 100, 200.  If the upper left of the image would be inside the viewport, you can either leave part of the viewport blank or adjust the image.  The same goes for the lower right.

Adjusting the size of the image for the zoom is a matter of [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) scaling using the `getScaledInstance` method.

In this example, you would use:

```
image.getScaledInstance(1200, 1200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
image.getScaledInstance(800, 800, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

You can choose a different scaling hint.

The formula for scaling an image is:

```
new width = original width * percent scaling
new height = original height * percent scaling
```

So, for 80% scaling of a 1600 x 1600 image:

```
1280 = 1600 * .80
1280 = 1600 * .80
```

The key to making all this work is to do all your graphics work on the largest image and scale it down for display.